# Limiting Total Threads in Multiple Executors

Tags: java, java-threads, executor

I have a six processes that send data to external servers. Each process runs multiple "Transfer" threads to improve performance and paralellism (latencies, big files, etc.). I have one executor per process with 5 threads max each.

Now, since the external server supports only 20 threads, and my processes try to run 30 total threads (6 processes x 5 threads each), some threads crash. I get it.

Is there any way of creating a "big thread pool" (with 20 threads) in Java to limit the total transfer threads to a maximum of 20 for all processes?

Alternatively, I was thinking of creating a **single** executor for all processes but then one process could hog all threads, leaving the other ones starving.

Comment: By process, do you mean each running in its own JVM?

Comment: No, all processes run inside the same single JVM. They are actual threads too.

Comment: The threads will not crash. They will only compete for resources.

Comment: A shared, fixed sized (20) thread pool executor should work. There could be a semaphore for each process to limit the number of concurrent tasks submitted to the executor.

Comment: @Raedwald Unfortunately, they crash when they try to open a connection with the external server that rejects the 21st one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use single executor and implement [bulkhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391809/what-is-bulkhead-pattern-used-by-hystrix) pattern for your processes.
Hystrix and Resilience4j have ready implementations, for example.

Comment: Seems exactly what I'm looking for. I assume Java doesn't offer any standard implementation, so I'll need to implement it, right?

Comment: You can implement it with standart Java objects like locks or semaphores or atomic counters, or you can use 3rd party library. Depends on your tasks and preferences.

Comment: Great, I think I'll use a single executor instead of 6, and will use a semaphore for each process (with size 5).